# Set Metadata domain with GDAL (python bindings)

Tags: python, gdal, c++, geolocation

I'm trying to set geolocation metadata in a gdal vrt with python bindings.

```
ds = gdal.Open('foo')
ds.SetMetadata ({'X_BAND' : '1'})
gdal.BuildVRT('bar', ds)
```

Results in a vrt with the following metadata

```
<Metadata>
<MDI key="X_BAND">1</MDI>
</Metadata>
```

However, I need the metadata to read:

```
<Metadata domain="GEOLOCATION">
<MDI key="X_BAND">1</MDI>
</Metadata>
```

I'm able to accomplish this using `ds.SetMetaDataItem("X_BAND", "1", "geolocation")` but would like to know how to do it with `gdal.SetMetadata`

I know the problem is with my failure to understand how swig is translating the python to the C++ so hopefully someone can quickly fix my syntax.
From http://gdal.org/python/

```
SetMetadata(self, *args)
SetMetadata(self, char papszMetadata, char pszDomain = "") -> CPLErr   
SetMetadata(self, char pszMetadataString, char pszDomain = "") -> CPLErr
```

Comment: Yes! That did it (as long as the "1" is in quotes). If you post this as an answer I will accept, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by passing a dict:

```
ds.SetMetadata({"X_BAND": "1" }, "GEOLOCATION")
```